# How to Check whether an IP is reachable or not, in codename one

Tags: java, ip, codenameone

We have sockets here to get the host / IP of the device.

How to check whether the URL host is reachable or not?

Just as we do in Java or android with Inet Address.

Comment: Are you using the builtin socket API, the sockets cn1lib or just standard HTTP with connection request?

Answer (score 0):

```
InetAddress.getByName(ip).isReachable(timeout);
```

Comment: Yes I have already tried that. This is not the solution for above problem.

Answer (score 0):

To check connection to an http server you can use something like:

```
ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
r.setUrl(serverUrl);
r.setTimeout(5000);
r.setFailSilently(true);
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
if(r.getResponseCode() != 200) {
   // no connection...
}
```

Comment: Hi San, Thanks for a quick reply. But This again giving me exception if I am trying with different IP. I have tried this code also earlier.

Comment: ConnectionRequest r = new ConnectionRequest();
     r.setUrl("http://"+IP+"/faculty-share/App-webservices/getalldata.php?user=rkv");
     r.setTimeout(500);
     r.setFailSilently(true);
     NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
     if(r.getResponseCode() != 411) {
        // no connection...
      return false;
     }
     else{
      System.out.println("Reachable");
      return true;
     }

Comment: I have set timed out very low. And yes this works. But Still I can see the exception in console. Also the response code is different as mentioned by you. Can you please explain me the logic behind this. I would be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 200 means OK response (reachability) so your code seems to have the opposite logic. Generally this is just trying to open a connection to an HTTP server? I don't understand what you mean by the logic behind this?